# Install older version of gfortran on windows (cygwin x64)

Tags: windows, cygwin, gcc

I'm using cygwin 64bit for windows. It offers all the packages you could want in the setup, but I can't find a way to get an older version of a package (gcc fortran compiler in my case). I have version 4.9.2 and I need version 4.4x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I can't find a way to get an older version of a package

There is no complete archive of older packages.

> If you really need an older package, you may be able to
>   find an outdated or archival mirror by searching the web for an old
>   package version (for example, gcc2-2.95.3-10-src.tar.bz2), but keep in
>   mind that this older version will not be supported.

---

#### Can I use Cygwin Setup to get old versions of packages (like gcc-2.95)?

> Cygwin Setup can be used to install any packages that are
>   on a Cygwin mirror, which usually includes one version previous to the
>   current one.
>
> The complete list may be searched at https://cygwin.com/packages/.
>
> There is no complete archive of older packages. If you have a problem
>   with the current version of a Cygwin package, please report it to the
>   mailing list using the guidelines at https://cygwin.com/problems.html.
>
> That said, if you really need an older package, you may be able to
>   find an outdated or archival mirror by searching the web for an old
>   package version (for example, gcc2-2.95.3-10-src.tar.bz2), but keep in
>   mind that this older version will not be supported by the mailing list
>   and that installing the older version will not help improve Cygwin.

Source [Cygwin FAQ](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.old-versions)